# TCPDF Some variables are not printing in Output file?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am new to TCPDF PHP Library for pdf creation. I can be able to print first column of a table but could not able to print the rest. Here is my Code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Admit Card</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/jquery-1.8.3.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'admit', 'width=800');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script> </head> <body>
<div id="mydiv">
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
//ob_start();
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Dummy Dummy');
$pdf->SetTitle('Dummy Dummy');
$pdf->SetSubject('Dummy Dummy');
$pdf->SetKeywords('Dummy Dummy');
// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' CIT Kokrajhar', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$html='

 <table class="table" border="1"> <tr>
            <td>Sl. No.</td>
            <td>Name &amp; Father Name</td>
            <td>Nos.</td>
            <td>Roll Number</td>
            <td width="98">Photo</td>
            <td>Signature</td>
            <td>Remarks</td>
        </tr>
';
//$html = ob_start();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

?>
<?php



//
        $username='root';
        $password = '';
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somedbname',$username, $password);
if(isset($_GET['exam'])){
    try{
        $center=$_GET['center'];
        $exam=$_GET['exam'];


        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $strquery="SELECT * FROM dummytable_2013 WHERE `centre1`='".$center."' AND `examtype` LIKE '".$exam."%' ORDER BY RIGHT(`roll_number`, 3) ASC";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($strquery);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$rs = $stmt -> get_result();
        $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $i=0;
        //print_r($rows);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $i=$i+1;
            $form_number=$row['form_number'];
            $name=$row['name'];
            $roll=$row['roll_number'];
            $examtype=$row['examtype'];
            $sex=strtoupper($row['sex']);
            $dob = $row['dob'];
            $category = $row['category'];
            $countrycode = $row['nationality'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $region = $row['region'];
            $examcenter1 =$row['centre1'];
            $examcenter2 = $row['centre2'];
            $examcenter3 = $row['centre3'];
            $fathersname = strtoupper($row['fathersname']);
            $mothersname = strtoupper($row['mothersname']);
            $paddress = strtoupper($row['paddress']);
            $caddress = strtoupper($row['caddress']);
            $examname1 = $row['exam1'];
            $year1 = $row['year1'];
            $grade1 = $row['grade1'];
            $percentage1 = $row['percentage1'];
            $examname2 = $row['exam2'];
            $year2 = $row['year2'];
            $grade2 = $row['grade2'];
            $percentage2 = $row['percentage2'];
            $examname3 = $row['exam3'];
            $year3 = $row['year3'];
            $grade3 = $row['grade3'];
            $percentage3 = $row['percentage3'];
            $ddnumber = $row['ddnumber'];
            $ddamount = $row['ddamount'];
            $dddate = $row['dddate'];
            $dddrawnat = $row['dddrawnat'];
            $ddbranch = $row['ddbranch'];
            $photo = $row['photoname'];
            $substr="substr";
            if($i%7==0){
                $pdf->lastPage();

                // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                // Print a table

                // add a page
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $html=<<<EOF

                <tr>
                        <td>{$substr($roll, -3)}</td>
                        <td>Candidates Name: 
                        Fathers Name: 
                        </td>
                        <td>{$substr($roll, -3)}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="{$photo}" border="1" width="95" height="105">
</td>
                        <td> &nbsp;{$i}</td>
                        <td>{$form_number}</td>
                </tr>
EOF;
//          $html = ob_start();
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
            }
            else{
            $html=<<<EOF


        <tr>
            <td>{$substr($roll, -3)}</td>
            <td>Candidate&apos;s Name:
            Fathers Name: 
            </td>
            <td>{$substr($roll, -3)}</td>
            <td>{$roll}</td>
            <td><img src="{$photo}" border="1" width="95" height="105">
</td>
            <td> &nbsp;{$i}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;{$form_number}</td>
        </tr>

<?php
EOF;
//$html = ob_get_contents();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
}
        }

                    //function to send email

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }   

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('rep/'.$exam.'.pdf', 'F');
ob_clean();
?>
</table>
</div>
<center>
<input value="Print The Sheet" class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" type="button">
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php    
}
else{
    echo 'session not set';
}
?>
```

The result in the TCPDF output file is
Only the content of first  that is above the mysql connect. And the first column variable is printing. Result is below

```
TCPDF Example Dummy Dummy
by Nicola Asuni - Tecnick.com www.tcpdf.org






Sl. No.   Name & Father Name  Nos.    Roll Number   Photo     Signature       Remarks




001





002





003





004
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem i figured was due to proper table column height and width. After putting proper height and width to all of the colums i.e., in the td fields the rest field was able to get the values.
Tcpdf is not printing values if there is not proper table properties. The problem is resolved now.